# python distutils try setup

Tags: python-2.7, cython, distutils

I am trying to compile some cython code files using distutils.core.setup
In order to prevent compilation from crashing but to continue as much as possible I put each file Extension in a try statement as such

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy as np

pyx = [#file 1
       Extension('file1',
       include_dirs=[np.get_include()],
       sources ["file1.pyx"]),

       #file 2
       Extension('file2',
       include_dirs=[np.get_include()],
       language="c",
       sources = ["file2.pyx"]),

       #rest of files
       ]

       # compile extensions
       for E in pyx :
           try:
               setup( ext_modules = [E], cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext})
           except Exception as e:
               print "THIS IS AN ERROR", e
```

All is working nicely except when there is an error, try and catch seems to be useless. The compilation will stop without going through except statement.

Any idea why and what to do?

Comment: Did you check if `distutils.core.setup` actually does propagate an exception if one of the extension modules does not build?

Comment: Yes I did. I introduced an error to verify the try and except but setup crashes normally without passing by the except.

Comment: Then I'd suggest firing up pdb and setting a breakpoint on any `raise` and trace the exception from there.

Comment: You are right. setup through SystemExit when it encounters an error. 
Proof: https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.errors

Answer (score 0):

SystemExit must be included in the except

```
# compile extensions
for E in pyx :
    try:
        setup( ext_modules = [E], cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext})
    except (Exception, SystemExit) as e:
        print "THIS IS AN ERROR", e
```